# jQuery specify append position

Tags: html, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="menulevel1">
  <a class=""</a>
  <ul class="menulist">
    <li class="menulevel2"></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

If the ul menulist exists, I want to add the class secondLayer
At the moment I am doing it like that:

```
var thirdLevel = $('<div class="secondLayer">');
$(".menulevel1 .menulist").parent().append(thirdLevel);
```

This adds the class as a child of li.menulevel1, however, behind the ul.menulist. I need it to be added before the ul.menulist, so after the link.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.insertBefore`](https://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/):

```js
var thirdLevel = $('<div class="secondLayer">second layer</div>');
thirdLevel.insertBefore($(".menulevel1 .menulist"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="menulevel1">
  <a class="">Hello World!</a>
  <ul class="menulist">
    <li class="menulevel2"></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```